# How to Cast Parent Class to Child Class

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I have a question, how can I cast the parent class to child class or return the child class
when I declare the parent class with some condition

For example : I have parameter side = 4 , then when I declare new polygon, could it possible have a way return the rectangle to me by parent class?

Also how can I know return is rectangle or triangle ? is it possible to do that?

The code like below:

```
Public Class Polygon
{
   public Polygon(int side)      
   {
     .....
   }
}

Public Class Rectangle : Polygon
{
}

Public Class Triangle : Polygon
{
}


Polygon Shape = new Polygon(3);
var t = Shape.GetChildClass();
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use a static factory method to create subclasses.

```
// For educational purposes only!!!
public class Polygon
{
    public static Polygon Create(int sides) 
    {
        switch (sides)
        {
        case 3:
            return new Triangle();
        // ...
        default: 
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(/*...*/);
        }
    }
}


var shape = Polygon.Create(3);
var isTriangle = shape is Triangle;
```

That said, going down this road is going to lead to a lot of trouble...

Certainly a polygon is going to have a sequence of the lengths of its sides or equivalent. Even that is not sufficient, for a rhombus might not be a rectangle. Throw in Square, Diamond, RegularPolygon etc and you have a mess. It is better to just have a Polygon class that has IsTriangle, IsRectangle etc methods. And you might need IsCongruent and other comparisons, too. It is much simpler to do in one class.

Answer (score -1):

Try to make functions like:

```
public bool IsTriangle()
{
   ...
}
```

Then,

```
if(Shape.IsTriangle())
{
   Triangle t=new Triangle(Shape);
   ...
}
```

Basically you need to determine the subclass type of shape within polygon and set different members of subclasses. It could be a mess.